# TSQL - De-duplication report - grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to create a report that ranks a duplicate record, the idea behind this is that the customer wants to merge a whole lot of duplicate records that came about from a migration.

I need the ranking so that my report can show which record should be the "main" record, i.e. the record that will have missing data pulled into it.

The duplicate definition is pretty simple:

> If the email addresses are the same then it is always a duplicate, if
>   the emails do not match, then the first name, surname, and mobile must
>   match.

The ranking will be based on a whole bunch of columns in the table, so:

email address isn't NULL = 50
phone number isn't NULL = 20

etc.. whichever gets the highest number in the duplicate group becomes the main record. This is where I am having issues, I can't seem to find a way to get an incremental number for each duplicate set. This is some of the code I have so far:

( I took out some of the rank columns in the temp table and CTE expression to shorten it )

```
DECLARE @tmp_Duplicates TABLE (
      tmp_personID      INT
    , tmp_Firstname     NVARCHAR(100)
    , tmp_Surname       NVARCHAR(100)
    , tmp_HomeEmail     NVARCHAR(300)
    , tmp_MobileNumber  NVARCHAR(100)
    --- Ratings
    , tmp_HomeEmail_Rating  INT
    --- Groupings
    , tmp_GroupNumber   INT
)

;WITH cteDupes AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personHomeEmail ORDER BY personID DESC) AS RND,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personHomeEmail ORDER BY personId)      AS RNA,
              p.personID, p.PersonFirstName, p.PersonSurname, p.PersonHomeEMail
            , personMobileTelephone
    FROM    tblCandidate c INNER JOIN tblPerson p ON c.candidateID = p.personID
)
INSERT INTO @tmp_Duplicates
SELECT  PersonID, PersonFirstName, PersonSurname, PersonHomeEMail, personMobileTelephone
        , 10, RND
FROM    cteDupes
WHERE RNA + RND > 2
ORDER BY personID, PersonFirstName, PersonSurname


SELECT * FROM @tmp_Duplicates
```

This gives me the results I want, but the group number isn't showing how I need it:

[image]

What I need is for each group to be an incremental value:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the sample data (via text, not a screenshot) that would lead to the current / desired outputs?

Comment: thanks, I figured it out, as long as I have one field that is always the same I can use dense rank: DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY personHomeEmail ) AS GroupNumber,